# Performance evaluation discussion with other project managers

Tags: performance

I need to talk for my team members individual performance with other employees working in different projects to get good relative ranking.Can you please suggest me on how to represent the team in a better way

Comment: Hi Siva, you're not really giving us a lot of information to work with here. Can you please tell us more about the project? What do you mean by "represent the team in a better way"? What type of ranking do you have in mind?

Comment: In our company a relative ranking is done and each manager represent the team members and in that peer group talks for his team with other managers and comes up with a consolidated relative ranking

Comment: I'm not sure performance management/review questions are directly PM-related. You might get more useful responses on: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/. That said, I'd agree with David Espina - sounds like a pretty arbitrary review process.

Comment: Hi Siva, still not sure if this is on-topic here, as Will suggests. However, if you can [edit] your question so this isn't so broad, and make sure it's clearly a project management issue, we can look at maybe reopening. It's difficult to give you a solid answer without more details, and even on the Workplace SE, I'm sure this would get quickly closed without edits. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a disservice to your team, and to the other teams, to present your team in a better way.  Evaluations is NOT about how well you argue, but is about an individual's performance to a standard benchmark and between themselves.

Instead, get the other managers to objectively score each, to the degree possible, so that your evaluations are precise and realistic.  While one manager may have all the stars or the scrubs, most likely each manager will have pretty much the same composition: a few stars, a few scrubs, and most right in the middle.